# How do we evaluate an intersection in fuzzy set to compare alpha cut values?

Tags: derivatives

I have given $\alpha$ in the interval $[0,1]$ and the $\beta$ interval $[0,1]$ and the condition is $\bigcap \alpha: \alpha\lt\beta [μ]\alpha = [μ]\beta$
How do I evaluate this condition to check for the condition?
$μ$ is the membership function of the fuzzy set.
Any help would be appreciated.

Additional info: my function is $\alpha = [1-\sqrt{\ln(\frac 1 {\alpha})}, 1+\sqrt{\ln(\frac 1 {\alpha})}]$ if $\alpha\gt0 = \mathbb{R}$ , if $\alpha = 0$ I have considered values from $0.1$ to $0.9$ and obtained different intervals for the above function but cannot validate the condition. In a way, I do not understand how to evaluate the intersection condition. Additionally, this is a representation theorem for the system of sets for alpha cuts. Hope this information is sufficient.

Comment: Would you like to share what you have tried/thought of so far?

Comment: So basically, my function is **Aα = [1-√ln(1/α), 1+√ln(1/α)]       if α >0
                                                 = ℝ ,                                        if α = 0**
I have considered values from 0.1 to 0.9 and obtained different intervals for the above function but cannot validate the condition. In a way, I do not understand how to evaluate the intersection condition. Additionally, this is a representation theorem for the system of sets for alpha cuts. Hope this information is sufficient.

Comment: Would you like to edit the question **body** to include that information? People usually vote to close questions before reading the comments.

Comment: Hope this helps, I'm new to this community.